# encoding parameter with special symbols in a HTTP call

Tags: java, http, urlencode, url-encoding

A string parameter in my url has special symbols (1008~38|1011~21|1022~26)

Using Java HttpUrlConnection in java to make http post call to a service.

```
targeturl = http://localhost.com/myapp/destinations=1008~38|1011~21|1222~26
URL url = new URL(targeturl)
```

url generated is following which looks like is already encoded 
    http://localhost.com/myapp/destinations=1008~38%7C1011~21%7C1222~26

Not sure if I have to encode the character '~' also. Please help

Comment: It seems correct as all url should be utf-8 encoded. The percent codes indeed match with utf-8 codes

Comment: should the tild ~ also be encoded ?

Comment: you don't need to encode the tild as far i know.
If a character is in the ascii table you don't need to % them.
If the url is utf-8 encoded you don't need to %code anything. It's optional.

Edit: URL constructor throw an exception if it can't construct a well formed Url :)